# MariaDB 5.5 and Ubuntu 13.10 -> 14.04 upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, upgrade

I have installed MariaDB (5.5.37+maria-1~saucy) on Ubuntu Server 13.10. Then I have upgraded Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS. Upgrade process has disabled repository for MariaDB 5.5. Current part of sources.list after dist-upgrade.

```
# deb http://mirrors.linsrv.net/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty
# deb-src http://mirrors.linsrv.net/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu saucy main
```

How do I keep future updates working? [Repository configuration tool](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/) doesn't offer MariaDB 5.5 for Ubuntu 14.04. Even if it would, I don't know how to change the repo and keep updates working. What should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
# deb http://mirrors.linsrv.net/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty
```

Just remove the # before this line and the text after the last `#`, so that the line looks like this:

```
deb http://mirrors.linsrv.net/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu trusty main
```

And you will receive updates as usual.